# Why use strtolower() when converting a string to capitalize from uppercase?

Tags: php

I don't understand this:

[1]

```
<?php
$test="HELLO WORLD";
echo ucwords($test);
// it will print HELLO WORLD
?>
```

[2]

```
<?php
$test="HELLO WORLD";
echo ucwords(strtolower($test));
// it will print Hello World
?>
```

Why use `strtolower` when converting a string to capitalize from uppercase?

Comment: Did you read the documentation about [ucwords()](http://php.net/ucwords)?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32564539/2943403

Answer (score 7):

From the [documentation for `ucwords()`](http://php.net/ucwords):

> Returns a string with the **first character of each word** in str capitalized, if that character is alphabetic.

`ucwords()` only cares about the **first character** of the word. It leaves the rest untouched.

Answer (score 3):

`ucwords()` does *not* convert the string to lowercase before converting the first letter of each word to uppercase. Nor does it convert the non-first letters to lowercase. It *only* converts the first letters to uppercase.

That is why you must explicitly convert those letters to lowercase before using `ucwords()`.

Answer (score 1):

In the following code
The variable $test is uppercase. The ucwords Changes only the first letter of each word. You can't see changes and the result with the variable are same.

[1]

```
<?php
$test="HELLO WORLD";
echo ucwords($test);
// it will print HELLO WORLD
?>
```

In the second code... 
All the string variable first converted to lower case with strtolower function
and then the ucwords function changes all first characters from the words as uppercase.

With strtolower the result is => "hello world"

After, the ucwords result is "Hello World".

[2]

```
<?php
$test="HELLO WORLD";
echo ucwords(strtolower($test));
// it will print Hello World
?>
```